# How to include a generated CSS file into a gradle project?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, sass, war

I have a web application with Spring Boot and gradle build. I generate a CSS file from SCSS files in the build directory and added the file to the generated WAR file. The file is added to the WAR file, but not present if I start the embedded web server from IntelliJ IDEA.

```
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "org.fabric3.gradle.fabric3-sass"

...

// Generate the CSS from the SCSS files
sass {
    inputFilePath  = "src/main/webapp/resources/scss/my.scss"
    includePaths   = "src/main/webapp/resources/scss"
    outputFilePath = "build/generated/src/main/webapp/resources/css/my.css"
}

war {
    dependsOn compileSass
    ...
    // Add the CSS to the WAR file
    from "build/generated/src/main/webapp/"
}

// I tried to add the CSS to IDEA but if I run bootRun the CSS is not provided by the embedded server
// the WAR file is build correctly and works fine.
idea.module {
    sourceDirs += file('build/generated')
    resourceDirs += file('build/generated')
    generatedSourceDirs += file('build/generated')
}
```

I expected the CSS to be provided by the embedded server after I added it to the WAR file.

Here is a part of the output of `unzip -l my.war`:

```
Archive:  my.war
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2019-06-24 08:24   META-INF/
      149  2019-06-24 08:24   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  2019-06-24 08:24   WEB-INF/
         ...
        0  2019-06-24 07:41   resources/css/
    31952  2019-06-21 14:11   resources/css/my.css
        0  2019-06-24 07:41   resources/js/
        0  2019-06-21 14:11   resources/js/my.js
```

The CSS is where it should be and works perfectly fine when I deploy it, but if I want to debug the application in my IDE and start it with `gradle bootRun` the CSS is not provided by the embedded Spring server. Only the WAR file works.

Comment: Could you provide a tree view of the `war` file? The output of `unzip -l your_app.war` would be great.

Comment: What Run/Debug Configuration do you use? Please try Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | **Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle** option. Does it work?

Comment: @Andrey: I added the option,but it did not help. I'm starting the application through the `bootRun` task.

Comment: `I'm starting the application through the bootRun task.` `bootRun` task does not use war artifacts. I assume you gets the same result when running this Gradle task from command line?

Comment: @Andrey: Your're right. Same problem. I need to add the directory with the generated sources as source set. Like `sourceSets.main.webapp.srcDir 'build/generated/src/main/webapp/'`, but webapp is not a known property. How can I add a folder to the webapp source directory?